# Sort items in a list according to the number in the item

Tags: python, list

I have a list which looks like this-

```
answer = ['toy3', 'toy4', 'toy1']
```

I want to sort it according to the number in the toy(ascending). So the list should look like this-

```
answer = ['toy1', 'toy3', 'toy4']
```

Comment: Can you look at this article, https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html. This is easy for you, like this ; answer.sort().

Comment: Do you want to sort only according to the number, or according to the string then the number, or the opposite? I suppose, also, that you would want 'toy2' to come before 'toy10'?

Comment: Do all the words are toy + number?

Comment: This seems like the result of poor/unfortunate design. Could you provide some context?

Answer (score 3):

Use the key parameter of [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
import re

numbers = re.compile('\d+$')

answer= ['toy3','toy4','toy1']

result = sorted(answer, key=lambda x: int(numbers.search(x).group()))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['toy1', 'toy3', 'toy4']
```

The idea is to extract the group of digits at the end and convert to an integer, then use this value as the key for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function as a key to [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html):

```py
>>> sorted(answer, key=lambda x: x[-1])
['toy1', 'toy3', 'toy4']
```

Comment: What about 'toy10'?

Comment: Good Point! @RaySteam's answer is the way to go then

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the integral number is just after the `toy` word in every string.

```py
answer= ['toy3','toy4','toy1','toy10','toy-1','toy200']
result = sorted(answer, key=lambda x: int(x[3:]))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['toy-1', 'toy1', 'toy3', 'toy4', 'toy10', 'toy200']
```